# multi-fingers UIPanGestureRecognizer behavor with CGRectContainsPoint

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a main view that divided into 4 equally sized sub-views.  I used UIPanGestureRecognizer with 3 fingers to trigger an event based on which 1 of those 4 views using the CGRectContainsPoint method.

My goal is that three fingers have to be in the same view when the motion started/ended to trigger the appropriated event handling for that view.

The problem was that if I start with my 3 fingers not in the same view (2 fingers in view1 and 1 finger in view2 etc.)  The event handling that got triggered was the one with 2 fingers at the end since I am using the UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded method etc.

Is there a technique to make sure that the event handling get triggered if and only if 3 fingers started at the same view (CGRect) and ended with the same view (CGRect)?

btw:  I am using the same procedure for other UIXXXGestureRecognizer and they all worked as designed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just compared the location for UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan state and the location for UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded to make sure it is within the specific view.